# How do I prove that the linear span of a set of vectors is equal to the set of vectors that satisfy an equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, span

The problem states that **H** is all the vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$, $[x,y,z,w]^T$, that satisfy the equation: $3x + 4y +z + 2w = 0$

I was given three vectors $\vec{u}=[1, -1, 1, 0]^T, \vec{v}=[0, -1, 2, 1]^T, \vec{w}=[1, -1, -1, 1]^T$.

In the first part of the problem I have proven that the vectors $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$, and $\vec{w}$ are all in **H** and that they are linearly independent. For the next part I have to show that span($\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$, $\vec{w}$) = **H**.

Is there a way of showing this through calculation?

Right now all I can come up with is that, since $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$, and $\vec{w}$ are in **H** and they are linearly independent, then all possible linear combinations of those vectors would be in **H**. But there might be other vectors that can satisfy the equation that are not in $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$, and $\vec{w}$. Or is there? How can I prove otherwise.

Comment: Obviously the dimension of $\mathbf H$ is three ...

Answer (score 1):

Since $u,v,w$ are linearly independent, you know that $\text{span}(u,v,w)$ has dimension 3.

Since H is the nullspace of the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}3&4&1&2\end{bmatrix}$ and $A$ has rank 1, $\dim(H)=\text{nullity}(A)=3$.

Therefore $\text{span}(u,v,w)=H$, since $\text{span}(u,v,w)\subseteq H$ and both subspaces have the same dimension.

Answer (score 0):

**H** is a proper subspace of $\mathbb R$, as the vector $[1,0,0,0]^T$ doesn't belong to it. So the dimension of **H** is strictly less than $4$. On the other hand **H** contains a family of three linearly independent vectors. So the dimension of **H** is at least equal to $3$.

Finally, the dimension of **H** is equal to $3$ and **H** $=\text{ span}(u,v,w)$.